# html add link for call selfFunction with arg obj

Tags: javascript, html, events, callback, literals

it possible inside html to pass a link with self function and pass arg **OBJ** from the scope

example

```
 function notifier_ADD(ZZZ) {
   let message = /*html*/`<a href="#" onclick="callback_WithArg_Scoped(ZZZ);">Run JavaScript Code</a>`;
};
```

how i can pass **ZZZ** in the event?

```
onclick="callback_WithArg_Scoped(ZZZ)"
```

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, it's a matter of injecting a variable intro a string. This would work: ```let message = `<a href="#" onclick="callback_WithArg_Scoped(${ZZZ});">Run JavaScript Code</a>`;``` :)

Comment: It would be better to avoid attaching handlers in the HTML markup entirely - attach an event listener instead.

Comment: not in my context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, template literals:

*Assuming ZZZ is a string.*

```js
function notifier_ADD(ZZZ) {
  document.body.innerHTML += 
  `<a href="#" onclick="callback_WithArg_Scoped('${ZZZ}');">Run JavaScript Code</a>`;
}

function callback_WithArg_Scoped(str) {
  console.log(str);
}

notifier_ADD('Ele from SO');
```

If `ZZZ` is an object, you can create the element `a`:

```js
function notifier_ADD(ZZZ) {
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  a.href = "#";
  
  a.addEventListener('click', function() {
    callback_WithArg_Scoped(ZZZ);
  });
  
  a.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Run JavaScript Code'));
  
  document.body.appendChild(a);
}

function callback_WithArg_Scoped(obj) {
  console.log(obj);
}

notifier_ADD({message: 'Ele from SO'});
```

Or, you can use `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()` **(This is for modern browsers)**:

```js
function notifier_ADD(ZZZ) {
  document.body.innerHTML += 
  `<a href="#" onclick="callback_WithArg_Scoped('${encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(ZZZ))}');">Run JavaScript Code</a>`;
}

function callback_WithArg_Scoped(obj) {
  console.log(JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(obj)));
}

notifier_ADD({message: "Ele from SO"});
```

Comment: if ZZZ are object it not work, so you can only pass a string or number value ?

Comment: @jon Perhaps describe the expected input types of ZZZ

Comment: @jon check for the updated answer with approaches regarding to objects handling.

Comment: the full context are here https://codeshare.io/add9wK 
at line 1623
I think your code is good for my context thank!